# Motivating the "Gaussian" aspect of GP

Tags: probability, regression

In one of [his lectures notes](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4780/2018fa/lectures/lecturenote15.html) on Gaussian Process Regression, Kilian Weinberger notes that

$$
P(Y\mid D,X) = \int_{\mathbf{w}}P(Y,\mathbf{w} \mid D,X) d\mathbf{w} = \int_{\mathbf{w}} P(Y \mid \mathbf{w}, D,X) P(\mathbf{w} \mid D) d\mathbf{w}
$$

Using this equation, he motivates Gaussian Process Regression, stating that multiplying two Gaussians will also produce a Gaussian.

My intuition tells me that the equation above has to do with the definition of conditional probability, marginalization, and perhaps the chain rule of probability. However, I am unable to hash out the intermediary steps to go from $P(Y\mid D,X)$ to the final integral.

I'm aware that

$$
p(a) = \int_{b} p(a, b) \, db
$$

from which we can easily deduce something like

$$
p(a \vert c) = \int_{b} p(a, b \vert c) \, db
$$

I'm also aware of the chain rule of probability, though I'm not entire sure if this is relevant in deriving the desired conclusion.

$$
p(a, b, c) = p(a \vert b, c) \cdot p(b \vert c) \cdot p(c)
$$

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: first equality is marginalization over w, second is Bayes' theorem

Comment: @MikeHawk I see the marginalization now. Can you please elaborate on the Bayes' part?

Comment: I'm not sure how much there is to elaborate, it is essentially a direct statement of the theorem

Comment: @MikeHawk Allow me to clarify. I'm curious to know why we have $P(\mathbf{w} \mid D)$ instead of $P(\mathbf{w} \mid D, X)$.

Comment: i see, you are right about that.there are two possibilities: either there are some additional independence assumptions between D,X and w (which i cannot comment further on since you did not define them) or it is a typo.

Comment: I think I was missing an independence condition ($\mathbf{w}$ denotes the weight of a regression model, and $X$ represents a test set, so it's probably safe to assume that they are independent). Thanks for the pointer.